# What Is the Significance of Geometric Construction?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history, geometric-construction

So, when I was in high school, I learnt several geometric drawings such as bisecting line segments or angles, to constructing a square whose area is the sum of two other squares etc. using a ruler and a compass.

Later, at a more mature level of my mathematics journey, I learnt these problems puzzled us since classical Greek era, and they constitute of the whole branch of Geometric construction.

But my question is, why? In particular, the rules of the game (you can only use a *straightedge* and a compass, no other tool) as well as some of the problems seem rather arbitrary, as well as rather primitive. I am not necessarily asking practical applications, but do these methods or knowing the drawing techniques reveal anything particularly interesting, about structure of real numbers or topology of 2D surface etc.? The problems seem useful to build intuitions of high school students, but beyond that, is there anything deeper that warrants a name (*Geometric Construction*) for this whole branch of mathematics, and something that mathematicians find interesting?

Comment: It is neither primitive nor arbitrary. See [this HSM post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2238/17308).

Answer (score 1):

Why do the constructions puzzle us? Or why do we still care?

This is sort of hard to answer if you haven't studied the original constructions. A few answers:

1. The notation we know didn't exist in 400BC. Complex thoughts on number theory, conics, etc. were expressed geometrically. Expression (i.e., notation) that may seem primitive to us now was not primitive at the time. The ideas were certainly not primitive. That message carries forward too. Cubics and quartics were solved between 15000-1600 without our modern algebraic notation. This astonishes me given how hard it is to read the original proofs.
2. Elements, for example, is a landmark in human history. The constructs it contains start with a handful of axioms and build out an elaborate knowledge structure, the first time this ever happened. Although high school intends to use geometry to convey this idea, I suspect it often fails to do so. Certainly it was a revelation to me to read Euclid as an adult, despite having gone through standard plane geometry in school.

Ultimately, it seems to boil down to this: would you like to know how thoughtful humans thought 2500 years ago? What they felt certain of? They had limited tools, but they had good thoughts, and they expressed them with the simple tools that anyone could find or create.

A suggestion: it would take a trained person only a few hours to read through books I and II of Euclid's Elements. After reading, could you reconstruct from memory the arguments that culminate in the identity $4xy=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$, or $xy=z^2$ for altitudes $z$ in right triangles, or $a^2+b^2=c^2$? These constructs provide such knowledge without any number systems.

Answer (score 0):

The field that suffices for being able to implement the geometric constructions in Euclid is the field of [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number), so that one doesn't need the full real number field in this context.  In general, the relation between geometry and algebra is a rich source of subsequent mathematical developments, such as Felix Klein's [Erlangen Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program).  The issue of which Riemann surfaces require the full real field, and which can be defined, say, over algebraic number fields, is also an interesting one where a lot of research has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric constructibility maens we can *define* an object in terms of Euclid's axioms. This is a clear advantage in terms of identifying and understanding properties of these objects. If, for example, we seek to explore properties of a reglar pentagon, we can use Euclid's axioms to define this pentagon and proceed with Euclidean axioms and logic to prove what we want. We (now know we) can't do that with a regular heptagon and need additional assumptions beyond Euclid's axioms to define and prove its geometric properties.